# Function on Django object - server side

Tags: django, database, server

I have a Django application and a corresponding API. Within the code for the application I have some functions and some computed fields that I am not exposing in the JSON returned through the API. If I am working locally, in the same location as the code, I can do something like this:

```
from pythonfile.models import ModelClass
pk = 'model-class-uuid'
mc = ModelClass.objects.get(pk=pk)   
mc.the_function()
```

My question is, can I do this on the server side?

Comment: Use @property decorator for computed attributes. It's a part of the standard Python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a user-defined function on the server-side, you can define the function as a Python function in your Django views file or in other files. When a specific view is accessed, you can call this function perform server-side processing.

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick response. I am fairly new to this, what do you mean by "when a specific view is accessed"?

Comment: I mean when you call a specific api.